# Moq: How to raise an event with non-null sender

Tags: c#, events, moq, raise

Consider this interace:

```
public interface IFoo
{
   event EventHandler SomethingHappened;
}
```

With Moq, I make a mock of the interface, and now I want to raise the event:

```
var myMock = new Mock<IFoo>();
myMock.Raise(x => x.SomethingHappened += null, EventArgs.Empty );
```

This works perfectly, but the problem is that the subscriber expects sender to be something (the IFoo that raises the event, actually) and not just null.

Therefore I want to raise the event like this:

```
myMock.Raise(x => x.SomethingHappened += myMock.Object, EventArgs.Empty );
```

but the compiler will not allow that - it seemingly only accepts `null` as sender. Why is that? Is there a way do do what I really want?

Comment: What error do you get? Also what is the signature of `SomethingHappened` ?

Comment: Try
`myMock.Raise(x=>x.SomethingHappened += null,myMock.Object, EventArgs.Empty );`. `x=>x.SomethingHappened += null`, this will tell Mock, which event to raise, rest is the argument as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using `.Net 4.5`, there's a change in definition of the `EventHandler<TEventArgs>` delegate, check the links for [4.5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x(v=vs.110).aspx) and [4.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x(v=vs.100).aspx), this ensures that though you are using a type of `IFoo`, which may not be assignable from `EventArgs`, still compiler doesn't complain as it would have in 4.0, but other aspect would be Moq framework would consider event as a standard delegate not event pattern, which needs to be called as:

`myMock.Raise(x=>x.SomethingHappened += null,myMock.Object, EventArgs.Empty);`

`x.SomethingHappened += null`, which tell the Moq framework, which event / delegate to invoke and rest will be standard argument in the form `object sender, EventArgs e`

Comment: Thank you very much for your fine explanation :-). Yes, I'm using .Net 4.5.

Comment: Welcome, then you shall care to accept the correct and complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the (object sender,EventArgs e) for SomethingHappened as below, which would let the subscriber know the sender is your moq object of IFoo

```
myMock.Raise(x=>x.SomethingHappened += null,myMock.Object, EventArgs.Empty );
```

Comment: Hey, that works - thanks, man! Seems I was confused by the null. I assumed that the null was transferred as the sender parameter, but appearantly this is not the case. But what does the null mean then? Why is it required?

Comment: You need to first understand the reason, why this is happening and also if you noticed, I commented the answer in the comments, much in advance. Check my answer and ask any doubt that you may have